Problem when trying to include Allauth form in django template
I have this custom form
templates/account/signup.html

{% load i18n %}
<h2> custom {% trans "Sign Up" %}</h2>
<form class="max-w-[500px]" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="form-group flex flex-row justify-between w-full mt-2 py-4 px-6 bg-white rounded-xl text-black">
        {{ form.username.label_tag }}
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group flex flex-row justify-between w-full mt-2 py-4 px-6 bg-white rounded-xl text-black">
        {{ form.email.label_tag }}
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.email.errors }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group flex flex-row justify-between w-full mt-2 py-4 px-6 bg-white rounded-xl text-black">
        {{ form.password1.label_tag }}
        {{ form.password1 }}
        {{ form.password1.errors }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group flex flex-row justify-between w-full mt-2 py-4 px-6 bg-white rounded-xl text-black">
        {{ form.password2.label_tag }}
        {{ form.password2 }}
        {{ form.password2.errors }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">{% trans "Sign Up" %}</button>
</form>

when open on its own everything work just as expected, but when i try to include this in base.html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    {% include "account/signup.html" %}
</div>

form looks like this:
included signup form
Any idea how to fix this?
When I open the signup.html normaly
<a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Allauth Signup</a>

the form looks OK and I can create new account.
I want include this html to base template, but for some reason the form is not rendered corectly.
